# Acronyms and glossary

Tags: glossary

I have to add both an acronym list and a glossary to a document. Where should I write the acronyms that I have to define? Let's say I used attention-deficit/hyperactivity disorder (ADHD) in my document. Should I write ADHD both in the list of acronyms and the glossary?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Put them both in the acronym list and in the glossary. It's not a lot of additional work presumably, and it can only help in making the document clearer.